# Display QTreeWidget branch lines within Maya (PyQt5)?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, maya

To start, I'm using PySide2 within Maya which is pretty much the same as PyQt5.

I'm creating a ui with a pretty simple QTreeWidget.  I guess Maya's default style choices do not show the branch lines connecting all of the tree items and I would like them, so I've been trying to add them back in (without success).

Here's some relevant code showing what I've tried:

```
import PySide2.QtCore as QtCore
import PySide2.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide2.QtWidgets as QtWidgets

# I'm defining the stylesheet string outside of my function (which is why it's all caps)
#
STYLESHEET = '''QTreeWidget {border:none;} 
QTreeWidget::item {height: 20px;}

QTreeView {
    alternate-background-color: rgba(35,35,35,255);
    background: rgba(45,45,45,255);}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(vline.png) 0;}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(branch-more.png) 0;}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
    border-image: url(branch-end.png) 0;}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
    border-image: none;
    image: url(branch-closed.png);}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings {
    border-image: none;
    image: url(branch-open.png);}'''

# and an excerpt from where I'm creating my QTreeWidget (inside a function)
#
tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
tree_widget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
tree_widget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
tree_widget.setStyleSheet(STYLESHEET)
tree_widget.setUniformRowHeights(True)
tree_widget.setItemsExpandable(False)
tree_widget.setHeaderHidden(True)
```

I also have a recursive function that goes through a nested dictionary to add `QTreeWidgetItems` to the tree widget, which I can show if you need...  After the items are added I use `tree_widget.expandAll()` to open them up.

I snagged all of the `QTreeView::branch` stylesheet items from the QTreeView section on this site: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html and since my tree will always be fully expanded, I probably don't need the `closed` items or the arrows, but I was trying to just get the defaults there first before trying to modify it...

Anyway, No lines (or arrows) are getting displayed...  After I added the branch items to the stylesheet string, the arrows that were there from Maya's default style disappeared as well (which is fine because I didn't want them anyway).  I know that at least part of the stylesheet is working since the atlernating color lines do work correctly.

So I guess the real question is how do I get those images to show?  I thought they might somehow be inherently stored in the PySide2/PyQt5 libraries, but I'm guessing not since nothing is showing...  How do I go about explicitly telling the stylesheet where the images are stored so they can be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer is easier than I suspected....  The issue I was having is related to how windows directories are separated with `\` instead of `/` ugh...

You can very easily put a relative or whole path to an image file in the stylesheet string and it will locate and use the file UNLESS you use a windows path (even if you escape out the backslashes).

So `url(C:\path\to\image.png)` and `url(C:\\path\\to\\image.png)` do not work.

But `url(C:/path/to/image.png)` actually does work - and fortunately finds the file even though the directory separators are incorrect for windows...

I ended up saving and modifying the branch images from the stylesheet examples website in my first post.  Once I had them saved in a location near the file I'm writing my ui tool in, I then generated their respective file paths and replaced the backslashes with forward slashes - which would look something like this: `VLINE = os.path.join(path, 'vline.png').replace('\\', '/')`.  Then I used string formatting to insert them into my stylesheet string and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5        import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # I'm defining the stylesheet string outside of my function (which is why it's all caps)
        #
        STYLESHEET = '''QTreeWidget {border:none;} 
        QTreeWidget::item {height: 20px; 
                           color: rgba(255,255,255,255);}   /* +++ */

        QTreeView {
            alternate-background-color: rgba(35,35,35,255);
            background: rgba(45,45,45,255);}

        QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
            border-image: url(vline.png) 0;}

        QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
            border-image: url(branch-more.png) 0;}

        QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
            border-image: url(branch-end.png) 0;}

        QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed,
        QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
            border-image: none;
            image: url(branch-closed.png);}

        QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings,
        QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings {
            border-image: none;
            image: url(branch-open.png);}'''

        TreeList = ({
            'Header1': (('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', )),
            'Header2': (('Item11', 'Item21', 'Item31', 'Item41',)),
        })

        # and an excerpt from where I'm creating my QTreeWidget (inside a function)
        #
        self.tree_widget = QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.tree_widget.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.tree_widget.setStyleSheet(STYLESHEET)
        self.tree_widget.setUniformRowHeights(True)
        #self.tree_widget.setItemsExpandable(False)         # ---
        self.tree_widget.setHeaderHidden(True)

        for key, value in TreeList.items():
            parent = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree_widget, [key])
            for val in value:
                child = QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem([val])
                child.setFlags(child.flags() | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
                child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
                parent.addChild(child)        

        items = self.tree_widget.findItems("Item2", Qt.MatchFixedString| Qt.MatchRecursive) 
        [it.setSelected(True) for it in items]

        self.tree_widget.expandAll()
        self.tree_widget.show()        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app        = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp      = App()
    #myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry... I guess I don't really see how this is answering my question... Where are those images located and how does your code find them?  Could you please explain?  (I also updated my question with the import lines I'm using... I'm importing from PySide2)

Comment: never mind... I figured it out - see my answer if you're curious... but, thank you for taking the time to answer!